# Can an array key be a string with embedded zero bytes?

Tags: php, arrays

Can an array key in PHP be a string with embedded zero-bytes?

I wanted to implode a multi-part key with embedded zero-bytes as the delimiter and use it as the key in an associative array, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Not sure whether this is a problem with the array access or with `array_keys_exists()`.

Does anybody have any idea? Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I be creating a multi-part key in another way?

To clarify, I am trying to eliminated duplicates from user-entered data. The data consists of a product ID, a variation ID, and N fields of textual data. Each of the N fields has a label and a value. To be considered a duplicate, everything must match exactly (product ID, variation ID, all the labels and all the values).

I thought that if a create a string key by concatenating the information with null bytes, I could keep an associative array to check for the presence of duplicates.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: `print_r(array("\00foo\00bar" => 'works'));` works for me and yes, you should use another solution. How about using a multidimensional array instead? Perhaps, if you can explain what you are trying to achieve we can find a better approach to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the PHP string documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> There are no limitations on the values the string can be composed of;
>   in particular, bytes with value 0 (“NUL bytes”) are allowed anywhere
>   in the string (however, a few functions, said in this manual not to be
>   “binary safe”, may hand off the strings to libraries that ignore data
>   after a NUL byte.)

From [the PHP arrays documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> A key may be either an integer or a string.

No mention is made of any special case for strings that are array keys.

So, **yes**.

Comment: Thanks, based on this I went back and determined that my code was in error.  I also ended up learning about the "serialize" function, that may have been a better idea than my original implode idea.

Comment: Is `NUL Bytes` a typo at "the Manual", or does `NUL` mean something?

Comment: @Jared: [DOS led everyone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUL) to talk about [ASCII bytes with value zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) as "NUL". It's not a typo; it's just a bit silly.

Comment: *abbreviated **NUL*** - That's *hilarious*.

Comment: It's an abbreviation of one letter. `NUL`, `NULL`, whatever.

Comment: @Jared: Yes, to fit into three characters. [For other characters, this abbreviation was more extreme.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII_Code_Chart.svg)

Answer (score 0):

Like I already said in the comments

```
print_r(array("\00foo\00bar" => 'works'));
```

works. However, there is no reason for any of the gymnastics you are doing with `implode` or `serialize` or null byte keys.

If you want to see whether arrays are identical, then you can just compare them:

```
$input1 = array('product_id' => 1, 'variation_id' => 2, 'foo' => 'bar');
$input2 = array('product_id' => 1, 'variation_id' => 2, 'foo' => 'bar');
var_dump($input1 === $input2);
```

will output `true` whereas

```
$input3 = array('product_id' => 1, 'variation_id' => 2, 'foo' => 'foobarbaz');
var_dump($input1 === $input3);
```

will give `false`.

Quoting the [PHP Manual on Array Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

> - `$a == $b  Equality TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.`
> - `$a === $b Identity TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.`

Also, PHP has a function for deleting duplicate values from arrays:

- [`array_unique` — Removes duplicate values from an array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

And when you set the second argument to `SORT_REGULAR`, PHP will compare the arrays for equality, e.g.

```
$data = array(
    array('product_id' => 1, 'variation_id' => 2, 'foo' => 'bar'),
    array('product_id' => 1, 'variation_id' => 2, 'foo' => 'bar'),
    array('product_id' => 2, 'variation_id' => 2, 'foo' => 'bar')
);
print_r(array_unique($data, SORT_REGULAR));
```

will reduce the array to only the first and the third element.